# html cursor as a circular menu (wheel menu / pie menu)

Tags: html, css, cursor

I am trying to change the standard cursor of my website to a circular menu. Here are some examples of circular/wheel/pie menus:

1. http://webdesigntutsplus.s3.amazonaws.com/155_WheelMenu/nav_wheel-css-only/wheel.htm
2. http://www.cssplay.co.uk/menus/cssplay-pie-menu.html
3. http://nikesh.github.com/Pie-Menu/

I would like to know if:

1. Is it possible to change the default mouse cursor to one these?
2. If yes, is it possible to change the content of the menus dynamically? For instance, taking the example number 1, can the text of the sub-menus (those that appear on the right side) be different regarding where the user has positioned/placed the cursor?

Comment: 1) Do you mean the context menu? The cursor is the actual mouse pointer, the context menu is what pops up when you right-click.
2) So, for example, a different menu would appear if you clicked somewhere in the header to if you clicked in a sidebar?

Comment: No, I mean that your cursor is the whole circle with options that you can see in option 1). So instead of having an arrow (default cursor) you will have the whole menu. Thus, if you move your mouse, your cursor (the whole menu) will move accordingly.

Answer (score 0):

You can hide the cursor by setting css `cursor:none` on an element. Then set a `mousemove` handler on that same element that renders your new "cursor" at the cursor position.

If rendering takes time, it's possible the user can generate mousemove events faster than you can render. To avoid poor performance, when you get a series of mousemove events in a row, faster than you can render, you should discard all but the last one.

That answers the question of *how* to do this. It's a different question whether or not you *should* do this. Taking the user's cursor away in way that they can't control is usually a bad idea. If you're doing this in a game or in a specific control rectangle on your site, that's not so bad.

Comment: Dear Vroo, thank you for your answer. How can this be implemented? How can I attach the circular menu to the mousemove handler? Can you please post an example or give me some links to learn how to do it? Thank you.

Comment: I can't implement this for you but here's a bit more detail: The mousemove event contains the cursor position. See the doSomething function in http://www.quirksmode.org/js/events_properties.html or just use jQuery. You need to place your menu there. You can create your menu as an html object and set its position to the cursor position or if you have a canvas element you just draw your menu at that position.